# Why do some of these export statements fail?

Tags: javascript

Folks,

I am just curious, why this works:

```
export default translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component)
```

or this works:

```
let NewComponent  = translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component)
export {NewComponent}
```

But this doesn't:

```
export translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component)
```

And nor does this:

```
export {translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component)} /* ERRORS */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference: [Guide on exports from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

There are two types of exports: named, and default.

In your invalid examples, the following export:

```
export translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component)
```

...doesn't work because the result of the expression cannot be identified as a named export (you've given it no name), and it's not marked as `default`. If you're curious as to how this differs when you compare it to the first example with default being set, think about how you would reference it in an import:

```
// Valid example

// exporting in exports.js
export default translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component);

// importing it another file
import translateResult from './exports.js';



// Invalid example

// exporting in exports.js
export translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component);

// importing in another file
// since it's not named, and there is no default, it has no reference.
import ?? from './exports.js';
import { ?? } from './exports.js';
```

The following export:

```
export {translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component)} /* ERRORS */
```

...doesn't work because it's syntactically incorrect.  However, had you named the result of this expression before hand, it would not throw an error (at least, not because of the export):

```
const translateResult = translate(['header'], { wait: true })(Component);
export { translateResult }; // works
```